# Springboot JWT Auth with Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jwt

I have an application that was working with JWT auth (without Redis)
Actually I'm implementing Redis but I'm having some errors that I don't understand..

We I sign in, the jwt token is responded ( but not created in redis.. why ? )
And another problem is that when i make a request, it throws
`...common.security.specific.jwt.JwtUtil.extractToken(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)" because "this.jwtUtil" is null`

I added all the code in order to find any relevant information that can be responsible of these bug..
Thanks for any help !

JwtUtil.java

```
@Service
public class JwtUtil {

    /**
     * Get the token from authorization header.
     *
     * @param request
     * @return token
     */
    public String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader(JwtConstant.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_STRING);
        if (authHeader.startsWith(JwtConstant.TOKEN_BEARER_PREFIX)) {
            return authHeader.replace(JwtConstant.TOKEN_BEARER_PREFIX, "");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
...
```

JwtTokenFilter.java

```
@Service
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private TokenService tokenService;
  private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
  private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

  public JwtTokenFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                  TokenService tokenService, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) {
    try {
      // Check for authorization header existence.
      String header = request.getHeader(JwtConstant.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_STRING);
      if (header == null || !header.startsWith(JwtConstant.TOKEN_BEARER_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
      }
      // Validate request..
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authorization = authorizeRequest(request);
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authorization);
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(e.toString());
    }
  }

  private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authorizeRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
      // Get token.
      String token = this.jwtUtil.extractToken(request);  // ***PROBLEM IS HERE***
      if (token != null) {
        // Get token key.
        JwtModel model = (JwtModel) this.tokenService.getSecretKey(token);
        // Validate token.
        Claims claims = this.jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(model);
        // Validate user authority/role if allowed to do the api dto.
        String user = claims.getSubject();
        System.out.println("user" + user);
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user);
        if (userDetails != null) {
          return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
              userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

JwtTokenFilterConfigurer.java

```
public class JwtTokenFilterConfigurer extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authManager;
    private TokenService tokenService;
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            // Map dto value.
            UserDataDTO req = this.getCredentials(request);
            // Authenticate user.
            return this.authManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    req.getEmail(),
                    req.getPassword()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) {
        try {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

            // Create token.
            System.out.println("Je passe");
            JwtModel model = this.jwtTokenProvider.createToken(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
            // Set token.
            this.tokenService.setSecretKey(model.getToken(), model);
            // Set key expiration on redis.
            this.tokenService.setKeyExpiration(model.getToken(), model.getExpDate());
            // Add token to authorization header.
            response.addHeader(JwtConstant.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_STRING,
                    JwtConstant.TOKEN_BEARER_PREFIX + model.getToken());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private UserDataDTO getCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Map dto value.
        UserDataDTO auth = null;
        try {
            auth = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UserDataDTO.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return auth;
    }
}
```

JwtTokenProvider.java

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.expire-length}")
    private long validityInMilliseconds; // 1h

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.issuer}")
    private String issuer; // 1h

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetails myUserDetails;

    @Autowired
    private UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
    }

    public JwtModel createToken(String email) {
        AppUser user = userJpaRepository.findByEmail(email);
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(email);
        claims.put("auth", 
                user.getAppUserRoles().stream().map(s -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(s.getAuthority()))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        Date current = new Date();
        Date expiration = generateTokenExp(JwtConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION);

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuer(issuer)
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(current)
                .setExpiration(expiration)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey)
                .compact();

        return new JwtModel(token,
                issuer, email,
                current, expiration);
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetails.loadUserByUsername(getEmail(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    public String getEmail(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Claims validateToken(JwtModel model) {
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .requireIssuer(model.getIssuer())
                    .requireSubject(model.getSubject())
                    .requireIssuedAt(model.getIssueDate())
                    .requireExpiration(model.getExpDate())
                    .setSigningKey(
                            secretKey)
                    .parseClaimsJws(model.getToken())
                    .getBody();
            return claims;
        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException("Expired or invalid JWT token");
        }
    }

    private Date generateTokenExp(Integer timeExpired) {
        Date current = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(current);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, timeExpired);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    private TokenService tokenService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Disable CSRF (cross site request forgery)
        http.csrf().disable();

        // No session will be created or used by spring security
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        // Entry points
        http.authorizeRequests()//
                .antMatchers("/users/signin").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/users/signup").permitAll()//
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**").permitAll()
                // Disallow everything else..
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // If a user try to access a resource without having enough permissions
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login");

        // Apply JWT
        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenFilter(
                userDetailsService, tokenService, jwtTokenProvider, jwtUtil),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Allow swagger to be accessed without authentication
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")//
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")//
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")//
                .antMatchers("/configuration/**")//
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**")//
                .antMatchers("/public")

                // Un-secure H2 Database (for testing purposes, H2 console shouldn't be
                // unprotected in production)
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**")
                ;
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Comment: could you please share entire project?

Comment: Not possible sry, but you can find some help on github with "JWT Token filter"

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add `@Autowired` before `private JwtUtil jwtUtil` in class `JwtTokenFilter` and also you can use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to automatically create a constructor that takes the `autowired` fields as parameters.